# Trying to make php login work with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cordova

I understand that for a login / register system to work within Phonegap, you have to use aJax with your php. I've got a sucessful php login and register page working but I'm unsure where to begin with jQuery / aJax a.k.a where I'm meant to put it, and what exactly I should be putting in. I was wondering if someone would know how to point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery

jQuery is a framework built on Javascript. Javascript is a client-side (browser) language . It runs on your device, unlike PHP that gets executed on the server.

You need to include jQuery in the HTML of your login page using script tags:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery provides a way to target any html element within your document and perform certain functions on that element. You specify what element by using the following syntax:

```
$(element).doSomething();
```

You can select classes or IDs:

```
<p id="myparagraph">A paragraph of text</p>
<p class="myparagraphclass">A paragraph of text</p>

$('#myparagraph').doSomething();
$('.myparagraphclass').doSomething();
```

### AJAX

AJAX is a method introduced with Javascript that allows a page to request another url along with the result of that request. You will need to use AJAX login with Cordova/Phonegap because the "app" you're building is based on Javascript.

Thankfully, jQuery provides some really nice and easy to use AJAX methods.

### Putting it together

I notice from a previous question that you have already created a PHP script that checks the login credentials are correct. [Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /public_html/access/login.php on line 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37295777/warning-mysqli-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-result-null-give)

**I have edited slightly the code within that question (/access/login.php):**

```
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/html5up-aerial/access/functions.php");
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    if ($username&&$password) {
            session_start();
            require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT ROOT'] . "db_connect.php");
            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database) or
                                                die("Couldn't find db");
            $username = clean_string($db_server, $username);
            $password = clean_string($db_server, $password);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
            *if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){*
               $db_username = $row['username'];
               $db_password = $row['password'];
               if($username==$db_username&&salt($password)==$db_password){
                  $_SESSION['username']=$username;
                  $_SESSION['logged']="logged";
                  //header('Location: home.php'); // Have commented this out
                  $message = "YOU ARE NOW LOGGED IN!"; // <- ADDED THIS
               }else{
                   $message = "<h1>Incorrect password!</h1>";
               }
            }else{
                $message = "<h1>That user does not exist!</h1>" . 
                                "Please <a href='index.php'>try again</a>";
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            require_once("db_close.php");
        }else{
            $message = "<h1>Please enter a valid username/password</h1>";
        }
        //header/footer only required if submitting to a seperate page

        echo $message; // ADDED THIS
        die(); // ADDED THIS
```

This will be the PHP script that AJAX requests.

Now we create the HTML document with a login form and include jQuery and write our ajax code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<form class="login-form" method="post">
  Username: <input name="username" /><br />
  Password: <input name="password" type="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>


<script>
    $('.login-form').on('submit', function(e) { // Listen for submit

        e.preventDefault(); // Don't actually submit the form
        var data = $(this); // Put the form in a variable

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/access/login.php',
            data: $(data).serialize(), // Make form data into correct format
            success: function(response) {
               alert(response); // Alert with the response from /access/login.php
            }
        });  
    });
</script>
```

To debug this code you will need to use Chrome development toolbar or Firefox Firebug. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!! That helps a lot :-)

Comment: @JessicaFryer if this solve your issue, you could accept the answer